# installation without cd or usb please help

Tags: system-installation

how do I install Ubuntu without having to burn to a cd or usb? I need this for class and the pop up for cd keeps coming up then it tells me my cd is too small

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug with the images for Ubuntu, in that they don't fit onto a CD.  You need to burn them to a DVD, or write the image to a USB.  If you don't have a USB, you'll have to burn them to a blank DVD.

Or, use the [Minimal Images](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and put one onto a CD.  It'll only take a little bit of space.  However, if you need UEFI support, you will need a full disk to make it work.

Comment: Or (with some restrictions, in particular UEFI support) you could burn the much smaller minimal CD and install the rest of the system over the network - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the reminder, I thought the MinimalCDs were dead and removed, but I guess I was wrong.  I added your data into the answer, if you have anything else to suggest, please do!  :)